# Java collection sorting

Tags: java, sorting, collections, comparator, comparable

When i run the below code, Collection.sort(l) will throw below exception.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   learning.CollectionSort cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable

```
public class CollectionSort {  
    public static void main (String[] args){
        List l = new ArrayList();
        CollectionSort obj1 = new CollectionSort();
        CollectionSort obj2 = new CollectionSort();
        l.add(obj1);
        l.add(obj2);
        Collections.sort(l);
        for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(l.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

This is because we have to implement comparable or comparator for sorting custom objects. Normally we will have properties in an object which are used for sorting.

But in the above code, we have no properties in this class. So is possible to sort the above list? Please share your thoughts.

Comment: Well if you want to sort, you need to implement `Comparable`.

Comment: Ummm, no.  The list has two `CollectionSort` objects in it.  To sort it, the sort method has to tell which object is "less" than the other.  How can it do that, if you haven't provided a way for it to know?  Just what did you think the `sort` was going to do with these objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But in the above code, we have no properties in this class. So is possible to sort the above list?

Yes, you could write a `Comparator` that orders based on hash code (`hashCode()`) or string value (`toString()`), and use that to sort the list ...

```
Collections.sort(l, new MyComparator()).
```

But it is unclear would be gained by that, as the resulting orders have no particular meaning.  Indeed, if you are free to choose whatever basis you wish for sorting, then why not sort the list elements by their index in the list?  Then your list is always trivially sorted without invoking any methods.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am aware that no meaning in sorting this. Just to know how it is working i tried this. And when should be use comparator and comparable in applications.

Answer (score 0):

Implement [Comparable Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) on `CollectionSort` class
 or

Create [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) implementation class to pass as parameter to `Collections.sort(collection,comparatorReference);`

[Collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) class documentation.